# Oracle Table Indexes: 1 vs many columns

Tags: sql, oracle

Hopefully this should be a pretty simple question but I couldn't find an answer for it anywhere (hard to search for though).

I have a table that has the following unique constraint

```
CONSTRAINT "MYTABLE_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("CUSTOMERID", "STOREID", "COUNTRYID") ENABLE
```

Obviously that works as an index if I use all 3 fields in a join, question I have is what happens if I use that table in a query but only join on CUSTOMER_ID? Will that aid performance in the same way or do I need to create an index specifically for CUSTOMER_ID?

Comment: this will aid performance, but only for customerid, for other columns you need separate indexes

Comment: If you're not familiar with `explain plan`, I'd suggest doing a little reading on how to use it. You could then write queries, with varying `where clause` criteria, to test what would, and what would not, use that index.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, Oracle will use a Index which contains more columns the same way as an index with less columns (as long as you use the leftmost columns).

Thats true for some joins as well as where predicates or FK checking.

Oracle [states](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96590/adg06idx.htm#1591):

> Composite indexes speed up queries that use the leading portion of the index.

The index with multiple columns is a bit bigger, so it will have to read some more pages (or needs to keep more in buffer cache). However having one index used in multiple situations is better as maintaining multiples.

BTW: here is a blog which shows plans for matching and failed index columns: http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/the-equals-operator/concatenated-keys

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the info! Just to check I've understood the single index above with all 3 columns will give performance benefits when used for joins on any of (CUSTOMER_ID) or (CUSTOMER_ID,STORE_ID) or (CUSTOMERID,STOREID,COUNTRYID), but not for (STOREID,COUNTRYID)?

Comment: yes. at least as long as your columns are not pathologically distributed :)

Comment: And keep in mind, if the index contains all columns you care about then it will avoid going to the table at all. So for example `select CountryID, StoreID where CustomerID = '1'` will be satisfied by a single index range scan.